I frame or module federation is more preferable to setup different applications in one portal through NEXTJS14
I have different small relates application developed by different languages and I want to collect through one portal. I used Nextjs 14 as a host so which one prefer Module Federation, or I frame please the remote applications are already developed by using different languages and my host also through development and use NEXT JS 14 TYPESCRIPT AND APP based routing .
I want need clear Recommendation. means please give me advice based on the above prerequisite.
